# dummy questions about keystore?

Tags: java, jboss, centos, keystore

I am new to java and jboss

I tried these commands on my Centos5.4 final machine
where I can find the .JKS and .dat files ?

```
keytool -export -keystore myhost-keystore.dat -alias myhost -storetype JKS -storepass jonpassword \
-file myhost-cer
keytool -import -keystore truststore.dat -alias myhost -storetype JKS -file myhost-cert
-noprompt -keypass jonpassword -storepass jonpassword
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've skipped the first step, which is to create the keystore. Following the instructions [here](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_ON/html/JON_Agent_Guide/JON_Agent_Guide-Setting_Up_Secure_JBoss_ON_Communications-Step_2.html), you should first run this command:

```
keytool -genkey -dname "CN=myhost.mycorp.com" -keystore myhost-keystore.dat -validity 3650 -alias myhost \
-keyalg DSA -storetype JKS -keypass jonpassword -storepass jonpassword
```

That will create the `myhost-keystore.dat` file in the current directory.  After that, you should be able run the `keytool -export ...` command, which will create the `myhost-cer` file, again in the current directory.  And finally, the `keytool -import ...` command will import that certificate into a new keystore file named `truststore.dat` in the current directory.

Note that JKS is a keystore type, not the name of a file.

Answer (score 0):

cacerts default jks is at

```
${YOUR_JRE_HOME}/lib/security/
```

But for JBoss it may not be enough.

There may be some config location under server instance